# What does "load" and "store" mean?

Tags: assembly, x86

[This tutorial](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) says the following:

> every **load** on x86/64 already implies acquire semantics and every **store**
>   implies release semantics.

But say that we have the following instruction (assume that `var1` is equal to `1001`):

```
mov eax, [var1]
```

This instruction can be interpreted as a "store" and as a "load":

- Store the value at address `1001` into `eax`.
- Load `eax` with the value at address `1001`.

So what does "load" and "store" mean?

Comment: it's relative to memory (what Bo said), because memory is somewhat "external" to CPU, if you code in assembly. The content of CPU (register values, instruction being executed) are immediately available to the CPU, content of memory must be loaded/stored from/to memory chip over the address+data bus (wiring of CPU chip with other chips on the board). Asm programmers tend to think like they are localized inside CPU, so "loading" value is reading it from memory and sending it to CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is relative to memory.

So load from memory, store to memory.